# Is there a way to unify the subqueries in this with clause into a single query? Would it improve performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Schema info:

v_ProjectMilestone references project via project_id

milestones can be internal or external (milestone.is_external=1)

Milestones have three date columns that we care about ( Actual, Revised or proposed)

They want to be able to see the percentage of milestones that have a value for each of those dates and all of those dates divided up between internal and external milestones and the combination of both for each project.

```
with AllMilestones as( 
                SELECT 
                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id) AS all_milestones,
                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and Actual_date is not null
                        ) AS all_Actual_milestones,
                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and Actual_date is null
                        and proposed_date is not null
                        and revised_date is null
                        ) AS all_Proposed_milestones,
                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and Actual_date is null
                        and revised_date is not null
                        ) AS all_Revised_milestones,
                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and 
                        (Actual_date is not null
                        or revised_date is not null
                        or proposed_date is not null)
                        ) AS all_scheduled_milestones,                  

                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and is_external=1) AS External_milestones,
                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and Actual_date is not null
                        and is_external=1
                        ) AS External_Actual_milestones,
                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and Actual_date is null
                        and proposed_date is not null
                        and revised_date is null
                        and is_external=1
                        ) AS External_Proposed_milestones,
                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and Actual_date is null
                        and revised_date is not null
                        and is_external=1
                        ) AS External_Revised_milestones,
                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and is_external=1
                        and 
                        (Actual_date is not null
                        or revised_date is not null
                        or proposed_date is not null)
                        ) AS External_scheduled_milestones,                                         

                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and is_external=0) AS internal_milestones,
                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and Actual_date is not null
                        and is_external=0
                        ) AS internal_Actual_milestones,
                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and Actual_date is null
                        and proposed_date is not null
                        and revised_date is null
                        and is_external=0
                        ) AS internal_Proposed_milestones,
                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and Actual_date is null
                        and revised_date is not null
                        and is_external=0
                        ) AS internal_Revised_milestones,

                    (select count(project_id)
                        from v_ProjectMilestone
                        where v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
                        and is_external=0
                        and 
                        (Actual_date is not null
                        or revised_date is not null
                        or proposed_date is not null)
                        ) AS internal_scheduled_milestones,

                    project_id


                from 
                    project pp 
                    inner join v_ProjectMilestone on v_ProjectMilestone.project_id=pp.record_id
)



select 
Cast(Round(
 (100.0*AllMilestones.all_actual_milestones)/ 
 nullif(
 (1.0*AllMilestones.all_milestones)
 ,0)
,0)as int) as percent_all_Actual_Milestones,

Cast(Round(
 (100.0*AllMilestones.all_Proposed_milestones)/ 
 nullif(
 (1.0*AllMilestones.all_milestones)
 ,0)
,0)as int) as percent_all_Proposed_Milestones,

Cast(Round(
 (100.0*AllMilestones.all_Revised_milestones)/ 
 nullif(
 (1.0*AllMilestones.all_milestones)
 ,0)
,0)as int) as percent_all_Revised_Milestones,

Cast(Round(
 (100.0*AllMilestones.all_scheduled_milestones)/ 
 nullif(
 (1.0*AllMilestones.all_milestones)
 ,0)
,0)as int) as percent_all_Scheduled_Milestones,

Cast(Round(
 (100.0*AllMilestones.External_actual_milestones)/ 
 nullif(
 (1.0*AllMilestones.External_milestones)
 ,0)
,0)as int) as percent_External_Actual_Milestones,

Cast(Round(
 (100.0*AllMilestones.External_Proposed_milestones)/ 
 nullif(
 (1.0*AllMilestones.External_milestones)
 ,0)
,0)as int) as percent_External_Proposed_Milestones,

Cast(Round(
 (100.0*AllMilestones.External_Revised_milestones)/ 
 nullif(
 (1.0*AllMilestones.External_milestones)
 ,0)
,0)as int) as percent_External_Revised_Milestones,

Cast(Round(
 (100.0*AllMilestones.External_scheduled_milestones)/ 
 nullif(
 (1.0*AllMilestones.External_milestones)
 ,0)
,0)as int) as percent_External_Scheduled_Milestones,

Cast(Round(
 (100.0*AllMilestones.Internal_actual_milestones)/ 
 nullif(
 (1.0*AllMilestones.Internal_milestones)
 ,0)
,0)as int) as percent_Internal_Actual_Milestones,

Cast(Round(
 (100.0*AllMilestones.Internal_Proposed_milestones)/ 
 nullif(
 (1.0*AllMilestones.Internal_milestones)
 ,0)
,0)as int) as percent_Internal_Proposed_Milestones,

Cast(Round(
 (100.0*AllMilestones.Internal_Revised_milestones)/ 
 nullif(
 (1.0*AllMilestones.Internal_milestones)
 ,0)
,0)as int) as percent_Internal_Revised_Milestones,

Cast(Round(
 (100.0*AllMilestones.Internal_scheduled_milestones)/ 
 nullif(
 (1.0*AllMilestones.Internal_milestones)
 ,0)
,0)as int) as percent_Internal_Scheduled_Milestones
,project.*,
AllMilestones.*

 from AllMilestones inner join project on project.record_id = AllMilestones.project_id
```

Comment: You absolutely could make this a single query instead of dozens of them. It would greatly improve performance. However, given the nature of your question and the code I see I have a feeling that you are planning on making this a new view. And since this new view is calling other views you have what is called nested views. This will totally undermine any performance improvements you would make. It seems perfectly logical but nested views is a sure fire way to confuse the optimizer. Check out this article https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: @SeanLange Actually this is going to be a report. and will be run as a query, It won't get run all that often but I still hate making so many subqueries when I know there must be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is quite complicated; again and again you must read the same table. What you need instead is conditional aggregation. I moved the `NULLIF` to avoid division by zero to the `WITH` clause so as not to have to repeat it in every line.

```
    with allmilestones as
( select
    project_id,
    nullif(count(*),0) as all_milestones,

    count(case when 
            actual_date is not null 
          then 1 end) as all_actual_milestones,

    count(case when 
              actual_date is null
              and proposed_date is not null
              and revised_date is null 
          then 1 end) as all_proposed_milestones,
    count(case when 
              actual_date is null              
              and revised_date is  not null 
          then 1 end) as all_revised_milestones

    ,count(case when 
              (Actual_date is not null
                        or revised_date is not null
                        or proposed_date is not null)
    then 1 end) as all_scheduled_milestones,

    count(case when 
            is_external=1
          then 1 end) as external_milestones,
    count(case when 
            is_external=1 and
            actual_date is not null 
          then 1 end) as external_actual_milestones,

    count(case when 
    is_external=1 and
              actual_date is null
              and proposed_date is not null
              and revised_date is null 
          then 1 end) as external_proposed_milestones,
    count(case when 
    is_external=1 and
              actual_date is null              
              and revised_date is  not null 
          then 1 end) as external_revised_milestones

    ,count(case when 
    is_external=1 and
              (Actual_date is not null
                        or revised_date is not null
                        or proposed_date is not null)
    then 1 end) as external_scheduled_milestones,

    count(case when 
            is_external=0
          then 1 end) as internal_milestones,
    count(case when 
            is_external=0 and
            actual_date is not null 
          then 1 end) as internal_actual_milestones,

    count(case when 
    is_external=0 and
              actual_date is null
              and proposed_date is not null
              and revised_date is null 
          then 1 end) as internal_proposed_milestones,
    count(case when 
    is_external=0 and
              actual_date is null              
              and revised_date is  not null 
          then 1 end) as internal_revised_milestones

    ,count(case when 
    is_external=0 and
              (Actual_date is not null
                        or revised_date is not null
                        or proposed_date is not null)
    then 1 end) as internal_scheduled_milestones

  from v_projectmilestone
  group by project_id
)
select 
  project_id,
  cast( round(100.0 * all_actual_milestones / all_milestones, 0) as int) as percent_all_actual_milestones,
  cast( round(100.0 * all_proposed_milestones / all_milestones, 0) as int) as percent_all_proposed_milestones,
  cast( round(100.0 * all_revised_milestones / all_milestones, 0) as int) as percent_all_revised_milestones,
  cast( round(100.0 * all_scheduled_milestones / all_milestones, 0) as int) as percent_all_scheduled_milestones ,

  cast( round(100.0 * external_actual_milestones / nullif(external_milestones,0), 0) as int) as percent_external_actual_milestones,
  cast( round(100.0 * external_proposed_milestones / nullif(external_milestones,0), 0) as int) as percent_external_proposed_milestones,
  cast( round(100.0 * external_revised_milestones / nullif(external_milestones,0), 0) as int) as percent_external_revised_milestones,
  cast( round(100.0 * external_scheduled_milestones / nullif(external_milestones,0), 0) as int) as percent_external_scheduled_milestones, 

  cast( round(100.0 * internal_actual_milestones / nullif(internal_milestones,0), 0) as int) as percent_internal_actual_milestones,
  cast( round(100.0 * internal_proposed_milestones / nullif(internal_milestones,0), 0) as int) as percent_internal_proposed_milestones,
  cast( round(100.0 * internal_revised_milestones / nullif(internal_milestones,0), 0) as int) as percent_internal_revised_milestones,
  cast( round(100.0 * internal_scheduled_milestones / nullif(internal_milestones,0), 0) as int) as percent_internal_scheduled_milestones

from allmilestones;
```

This should be as fast as it gets, as you'd read the table only once. I hope I got it right that you want one result row per project.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can replace all the subqueries with CASE expressions that check the conditions in the WHERE clauses of each subquery.

For example, your first two subqueries would be replaced with:

```
 count(project_id) AS all_milestones,
 SUM(CASE WHEN Actual_date is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS all_Actual_milestones,
```

And so on.

As to whether it would perform any better, there is no way I know of to be sure other than to try it.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. You beat @ThorstenKettner by 3 min but his solution was a bit more complete. I wish I could mark you both correct.